# C# and passing user defined types to SQL server over procedure parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, geojson

Been searching around a bit now for this and haven't had much luck.  So here is what I'm trying to do.

Basically I have some C# model in the form of a GEOJson structure.  So I can create new features and featureCollections, etc.  When I serialize it, it spits out some nicely formatted GEOJson.

Now I'd like to persist this into the database.  To do so, I'd like to simply pass my entire "model" (either a FeatureCollection or an individual Feature...) straight into the stored procedure, and the procedure will handle pushing values to wherever they need to go.  Is it possible to do this in SQL Server?  I am somewhat new to SQL Server and have mostly worked with Oracle, and I've done something like this in the past with Oracle's user-defined types.  But not sure if SQL server can do a similar thing.

Here is what my JSON serialized would look like:

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [{
            "Type" : "Feature",
            "Properties" : {
                "name" : null,
                "description" : "Some Site Boundaries",
                "featureId" : 12,
                "featureTypeCode" : "siteboundary",
                "locationHierarchy" : {
                    "city" : {
                        "shortName" : "Long Beach",
                        "longName" : "Long Beach",
                        "hierarchyId" : 7,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 4
                    },
                    "state" : {
                        "shortName" : "CA",
                        "longName" : "California",
                        "hierarchyId" : 4,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 3
                    },
                    "country" : {
                        "shortName" : "U.S.A",
                        "longName" : "United States of America",
                        "hierarchyId" : 3,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 2
                    }
                },
                "floors" : []
            },
            "Geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [[[-118.1400864, 33.8324338], [-118.1401331, 33.8148000], [-118.1675695, 33.8148116], [-118.1677493, 33.8324253], [-118.1400864, 33.8324338]]]
            }
        }, {
            "Type" : "Feature",
            "Properties" : {
                "name" : null,
                "description" : "Some place",
                "featureId" : 71,
                "featureTypeCode" : "siteboundary",
                "locationHierarchy" : {
                    "city" : {
                        "shortName" : "St Louis",
                        "longName" : "St Louis",
                        "hierarchyId" : 8,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 6
                    },
                    "state" : {
                        "shortName" : "MO",
                        "longName" : "Missouri",
                        "hierarchyId" : 6,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 3
                    },
                    "country" : {
                        "shortName" : "U.S.A",
                        "longName" : "United States of America",
                        "hierarchyId" : 3,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 2
                    }
                },
                "floors" : []
            },
            "Geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [[[-90.3590381, 38.7637456], [-90.3390834, 38.7637456], [-90.3390834, 38.7474431], [-90.3590381, 38.7474431], [-90.3590381, 38.7637456]]]
            }
        }, {
            "Type" : "Feature",
            "Properties" : {
                "name" : null,
                "description" : null,
                "featureId" : 140,
                "featureTypeCode" : "siteboundary",
                "locationHierarchy" : {
                    "city" : {
                        "shortName" : "Mesa",
                        "longName" : "Mesa",
                        "hierarchyId" : 9,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 5
                    },
                    "state" : {
                        "shortName" : "AZ",
                        "longName" : "Arizona",
                        "hierarchyId" : 5,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 3
                    },
                    "country" : {
                        "shortName" : "U.S.A",
                        "longName" : "United States of America",
                        "hierarchyId" : 3,
                        "hierarchyParentId" : 2
                    }
                },
                "floors" : []
            },
            "Geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [[[-111.7369067, 33.4783391], [-111.7368442, 33.4653505], [-111.7170835, 33.4653505], [-111.7170835, 33.4782348], [-111.7369067, 33.4783391]]]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in the application layer I was thinking to simply pass the entire model of this right into SQL server in some way... such as:

```
public int CreateFeature(Feature json)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            int row;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_smmConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.CreateFeature", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // set up the parameters
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@parm1in", SqlDbType.VarChar, 7);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Json", SqlDbType.Structured);

                // set parameter values
                cmd.Parameters["@Json"].Value = json;

                conn.Open();
                row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            return row;
        }
```

Then I thought the procedure in SQL Server can simply catch that variable and parse through it as needed:

```
SELECT @Json.feature[0].Type;
```

etc.....

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using? Starting from 2016 there will be a native JSON support in SQL Server (to some extent, that is). I believe it's possible to find some CTP and play with it until the release date.

Comment: Yeah I read up on that... OPENJSON I believe.  Not running 2016 though, so that option is out.  I think instead of dumping hours trying to figure this one out I'm simply going to do it the poor man's way and create procedure(s) with the necessary parameters, using each one as needed.  Truth be told there's not "that" many.. I just wanted to have a slick way of doing this and learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Entity Framework?

You can do this by creating the whole data store logic inside a stored procedure but I would suggest you not to do this. It is always painful to write stored procedures and to maintain. One of the main reasons for using stored procedures is the need for a really intensive database usage and high volume of repetitive operations since they are cached in the DB server. I don't know if this is your case?

You can read about it here:  http://www.seguetech.com/blog/06/04/Advantage-drawbacks-stored-procedures-processing-data